# XULRunner , Python and Django : How to?

Tags: django, xulrunner

How to add Python and Django with XULRunner  !?
Found [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_XULRunner_with_Python) useful , but somehow i was not able to add django !

Any idea ?!

Comment: Why do you need django with XULRunner?

Comment: Trying to make my django project as desktop app

Answer (score 0):

Having a custom build of XULRunner with Python XPCOM bindings is one thing. But running a Django app on top of XULRunner is next to impossible. Django does not have helpers to create XUL layouts, Django is built around an HTTP architecture. How would you even imagine that Django will help you with a desktop app? What would be the desktop equivalent of the URLs? Events like onclick?

Comment: I know those facts , but so far , i am wondering if someone did that before . My goal is make my django projects acts as desktop apps . I had a problem packing Django apps as desktop apps using Cx_freeze , so as i tried Xulrunner/Python i had this idea of packing Django with it and using XULRunner as an interface for my app . that was the idea so far .

Comment: I've been thinking a bit about this and the easy way would be that the desktop application to run a local server and serve a Django powered applications from that server (hiding the address bar). I don't know how easy would that be with the Python XPCOM bindings though. Probably nobody has done that before.